# How can I measure the RAM consumption and the time of computing in Julia?

Tags: julia, ubuntu-16.04, ram, memory-consumption

I'm developing different discretization schemes and in order to find out which is the most efficient one I would like to determine the maximum RAM consumption and the time that takes to do an specific task, such as solving a system of equations, overwriting a matrix or writing the data to a file.

Is there any kind of code or something for doing what I need?
I'm using Julia in Ubuntu by the way, but I could do it in Windows as well.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just compute the number of bytes your arrays will take up. That's a pretty good estimate.

Comment: If you want to know the additional memory used during computation then `BenchmarkTools.jl` should help: https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl

Answer (score 1):

I love using the built-in `@time` for this kind of thing. See ["Measure performance with @time and pay attention to memory allocation"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#Measure-performance-with-[@time](@ref)-and-pay-attention-to-memory-allocation-1). Example:

```
julia> @time myAwesomeFunction(tmp);
  1.293542 seconds (22.08 M allocations: 893.866 MiB, 6.62% gc time)
```

This prints out time, the number of memory allocations, the size of memory allocations, and the percent time spent garbage collecting ("gc"). ***Always run this at least twice***—the first run will be dominated by compile times!

Also consider [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl). This will run the code multiple times, with some cool variable interpolation tricks, and give you better runtime/memory estimates:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools, Compat

julia> @btime myAwesomeFunction($tmp);
  1.311 s (22080097 allocations: 893.87 MiB)
```

(My other favorite performance-related thing is the `@code_*` family of functions like [`@code_warntype`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#man-code-warntype-1).)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `BenchmarkTools.jl` measures total memory use, not peak.  I haven't found pure Julia code to measure this, but perhaps [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Julia/comments/g55kox/recording_ongoing_peak_memory_usage/) is relevant.